# How to make one sorted list out of two already sorted lists

Tags: list, sorting, merge, prolog

In Prolog I have to figure out a way how to combine two already sorted lists into one sorted list. So in other words: from 2 lists I have to compare the heads and add the smallest to a new list. I think I've gotten pretty far, but somehow it just doesn't work and I can't figure out why not. I don't get any errors BTW. It just gives `false` back.

So, I hope someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
sort([],L,L).
sort(L,[],L).
sort([Head1|Tail1],[Head2|Tail2],L) :- 
    Head1 < Head2 -> append([Head1],L,L2), sort(Tail1,[Head2|Tail2],L2) ; 
    Head1 > Head2 -> append([Head2],L,L2), sort([Head1|Tail1],Tail2,L2) ; 
    Head1 == Head2 -> append([Head1],L,L2), append([Head2],L2,L3), 
                                            sort(Tail1,Tail2,L3).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SWI Prolog there's `merge/3` built-in predicate that does exactly that. So you shouldn't call your predicate "sort"; it's not. It's "merge".

Next, let's read your definition.

```
merge([H1|T1], [H2|T2], L) :-
```

means, merging the two lists produces the merged list `L`. So far, so good.

```
    H1 < H2 -> append([H1],L,L2), merge(T1,[H2|T2],L2)
```

means, in case `H1 < H2`, prefixing the *answer list* `L` with `H1` gives `L2`, which is the result of merging ... Wait, what? Does that make sense?

Prolog is not Basic. What we write are not "commands" to "do" stuff <sub>(well, they are, but in a roundabout way)</sub>.  If we want to say that `H1` is the head element of `L`, we say it:

```
               L = [H1|L2],        merge(T1,[H2|T2],L2) 
        %% or: append([H1],L2,L),
```

etc. Now this makes sense. :)

Comment: okay, thanks. But i have to create something for myself. its an assignment.

Comment: @Haile they aren't, but we can still provide guidance... For instance here the OP asked what were they doing wrong, so I think I've answered that - without giving away the full code. Now if the OP asked for a full code, and I didn't provide it, perhaps then my answer would be considered *not a full answer* and some big-wig supervisor (I mean, "moderator") would downvote it and took me some rep away... I dunno. Fortunately, the question here was not such.

Comment: @WillNess Sure. I misread his comment, thought he was asking for the code of the merge/3 predicate you cited.

Comment: @Haile nevermind that. :) BTW `listing(merge)` gives me that code. :) And it doesn't use `<`.

Answer (score 5):

You should simplify your code a bit:

```
sort([],L,L).
sort(L,[],L).
sort([Head1|Tail1], [Head2|Tail2], L) :- 
    Head1 < Head2 -> L = [Head1|R], sort(Tail1,[Head2|Tail2],R) ;
    Head1 > Head2 -> L = [Head2|R], sort([Head1|Tail1],Tail2,R) ;
    L = [Head1,Head2|R], sort(Tail1,Tail2,R).
```

test:

```
?- sort([1,2,4,5,18],[1,3,5,10],R).
R = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 18] .
```

Naming such predicate *sort* is really misleading, *merge* would be much better....

*edit* `L = [Head1,Head2|R]` instead of `L = [Head1|R]` where Head1=Head2 (having failed the previous tests) departs from sort/2 Prolog semantic, that removes duplicates.

Comment: succeeds twice for `[], []`

Answer (score 1):

Telling from the code in your question, you are merging sorted lists of numbers.
If these numbers are all integers and if your Prolog system offers [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd), consider using code presented here. Why?

- The implementation preserves [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity).
- The code is monotone, making it robust and flexible: always get logically sound answers, even when working for non-ground data.
- The main predicate `sorted1_sorted2_merged/3` behaves like a real relation.
- Unlike the builtin `sort/2`, this code keeps all duplicates (in exactly the same multiplicities).
- Regarding equal items in the lists to be merged, it behaves reasonable: 
  Items in input #1 that are equal to some items in input #2 precede those in the merged result.
- The implementation is efficient in the sense that it does not leave useless choicepoints with goals like `sorted1_sorted2_merged([1,3,5],[2,4,5,6],Zs)`.

Without any further ado... here's the code:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

sorted1_sorted2_merged([]    ,Ys,Ys).
sorted1_sorted2_merged([X|Xs],Ys,Zs) :-
   sorted2_hd1_tl1_merged(Ys,X,Xs,Zs).

hd1_tl1_hd2_tl2_merged(X,Xs,Y,Ys,Zs) :-
   zcompare(Op,X,Y),
   op_hd1_tl1_hd2_tl2_merged(Op,X,Xs,Y,Ys,Zs).

sorted1_hd2_tl2_merged([]    ,Y,Ys,[Y|Ys]).
sorted1_hd2_tl2_merged([X|Xs],Y,Ys,Zs) :- 
   hd1_tl1_hd2_tl2_merged(X,Xs,Y,Ys,Zs).

sorted2_hd1_tl1_merged([]    ,X,Xs,[X|Xs]).
sorted2_hd1_tl1_merged([Y|Ys],X,Xs,Zs) :-
   hd1_tl1_hd2_tl2_merged(X,Xs,Y,Ys,Zs).

op_hd1_tl1_hd2_tl2_merged(<,X,Xs,Y,Ys,[X|Zs]) :-
   sorted1_hd2_tl2_merged(Xs,Y,Ys,Zs).
op_hd1_tl1_hd2_tl2_merged(=,X,Xs,Y,Ys,[X|Zs]) :- 
   sorted1_hd2_tl2_merged(Xs,Y,Ys,Zs).
op_hd1_tl1_hd2_tl2_merged(>,X,Xs,Y,Ys,[Y|Zs]) :- 
   sorted1_hd2_tl2_merged(Ys,X,Xs,Zs).
```

On to some queries! First:

```
?- sorted1_sorted2_merged([1,3,4,6],[2,4,5,5,7],Xs).
Xs = [1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,7].         % succeeds deterministically
```

Does it work in the "other directions", too?

```
?- sorted1_sorted2_merged([1,3,4,6],Ys,[1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,7]).
Ys = [2,4,5,5,7] ;                % succeeds, but leaves behind choicepoint
false.

?- sorted1_sorted2_merged(Xs,[2,4,5,5,7],[1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,7]).
Xs = [1,3,4,6] ;                  % succeeds, but leaves behind choicepoint
false.
```

At last, a quite general use:

```
?- sorted1_sorted2_merged(Xs,Ys,[0,1,2,3]).
Xs = [       ], Ys = [0,1,2,3] ;
Xs = [0,1,2,3], Ys = [       ] ;
Xs = [0      ], Ys = [  1,2,3] ;
Xs = [0,1    ], Ys = [    2,3] ;
Xs = [0,1,2  ], Ys = [      3] ;
Xs = [0,1,  3], Ys = [      2] ;
Xs = [0,  2,3], Ys = [      1] ;
Xs = [0,    3], Ys = [  1,2  ] ;
Xs = [0,  2  ], Ys = [  1,  3] ;
Xs = [  1,2,3], Ys = [0      ] ;
Xs = [    2,3], Ys = [0,1    ] ;
Xs = [      3], Ys = [0,1,2  ] ;
Xs = [    2  ], Ys = [0,1,  3] ;
Xs = [  1    ], Ys = [0,  2,3] ;
Xs = [  1,2  ], Ys = [0,    3] ;
Xs = [  1,  3], Ys = [0,  2  ] ;
false.
```